# Subsetting based on first three letters in R

Tags: r, variables, subset

[image: ***Subset***]

Hey, I want to make a subset of this dataset base on the first three letters that serve as idents for the cities. How would I go around that in R?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Also, post your code in a way we can easily read it into R, and not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the OP wanted to `split` the dataset based on the  **first three letters** in the column names.  We can either use a `substr` or `sub` to create a grouping vector.

```
grp <- substr(colnames(df1), 1, 3)
```

or with `sub`

```
grp <- sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", colnames(df1))
```

Or another option is to remove the substring that starts from `_`.

```
grp <- sub("_.*", "", colnames(df1))
```

Based on the "grp", we can split the column names to a `list` and subset the dataset.

```
lst <- lapply(split(colnames(df1), grp), function(nm) df1[nm])
lst
#$DFW
#  DFW_rain DFW_snow DFW_fog DFW_tstorm DFW_hail
#1        0        0       0          0        0
#2        1        0       0          0        0
#3        1        0       0          0        0
#4        0        0       0          0        0

#$ELP
#  ELP_tmax ELP_tmean ELP_tmin ELP_dewmax ELP_dewmean ELP_dewmin ELP_hummax ELP_hummean ELP_hummin ELP_prsmax ELP_prsmean ELP_prsmin ELP_windmax ELP_windmean ELP_winddir
#1       64        55       46         42          34         23         73          47         22      29.89       29.83      29.75          29           12         243
#2       57        46       35         32          26         21         70          48         26      29.96       29.86      29.72          39           13         227
#3       46        40       34         25          13          3         59          36         17      30.43       30.17      29.92          37           18         306
#4       45        36       27         17          11          7         63          39         15      30.51       30.39      30.23          14            8          15
#  ELP_precip ELP_cloud ELP_rain ELP_snow ELP_fog ELP_tstorm ELP_hail
#1          0         3        0        0       0          0        0
#2          0         1        0        0       0          0        0
#3          0         1        0        0       0          0        0
#4          0         0        0        0       0          0        0
```

The "lst" is a `list` of `data.frame`s.  It is better to do all the operations within the `list` instead of having several objects in the global environment

But, if we need separate data.frame objects (not recommended)

```
list2env(setNames(lst, paste0("df", names(lst))),
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
dfDFW
#   DFW_rain DFW_snow DFW_fog DFW_tstorm DFW_hail
#1        0        0       0          0        0
#2        1        0       0          0        0
#3        1        0       0          0        0
#4        0        0       0          0        0
```

---

Instead of `split`ting if we need to extract only a particular column we can `grep` with the values of 'grp'.  For example

```
 Un1 <- unique(grp)
 df1[grep(Un1[1], colnames(df1))]
 #     DFW_rain DFW_snow DFW_fog DFW_tstorm DFW_hail
 #1        0        0       0          0        0
 #2        1        0       0          0        0
 #3        1        0       0          0        0
 #4        0        0       0          0        0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DFW_rain = c(0, 1, 1, 0), 
DFW_snow = c(0, 0, 0, 0), DFW_fog = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
DFW_tstorm = c(0, 0, 0, 0), DFW_hail = c(0, 
0, 0, 0), 
ELP_tmax = c(64, 57, 46, 45), ELP_tmean = c(55, 46, 
40, 36), ELP_tmin = c(46, 35, 34, 27), ELP_dewmax = c(42, 32, 
25, 17), ELP_dewmean = c(34, 26, 13, 11), ELP_dewmin = c(23, 
21, 3, 7), ELP_hummax = c(73, 70, 59, 63), ELP_hummean = c(47, 
48, 36, 39), ELP_hummin = c(22, 26, 17, 15), ELP_prsmax = c(29.89, 
29.96, 30.43, 30.51), ELP_prsmean = c(29.83, 29.86, 30.17, 30.39
), ELP_prsmin = c(29.75, 29.72, 29.92, 30.23),
ELP_windmax = c(29, 39, 37, 14), ELP_windmean = c(12, 13, 
18, 8), ELP_winddir = c(243, 
227, 306, 15), ELP_precip = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
ELP_cloud = c(3, 1, 1, 0), ELP_rain = c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
ELP_snow = c(0, 0, 0, 0), ELP_fog = c(0,0, 0, 0), 
ELP_tstorm = c(0, 0, 0, 0), ELP_hail = c(0, 0, 0, 0
)), .Names = c("DFW_rain", "DFW_snow", "DFW_fog", 
"DFW_tstorm", "DFW_hail", "ELP_tmax", "ELP_tmean", 
"ELP_tmin", "ELP_dewmax", "ELP_dewmean", "ELP_dewmin", 
"ELP_hummax", "ELP_hummean", "ELP_hummin", 
"ELP_prsmax", "ELP_prsmean", "ELP_prsmin", "ELP_windmax",
 "ELP_windmean", "ELP_winddir", "ELP_precip", 
 "ELP_cloud", "ELP_rain", "ELP_snow", 
 "ELP_fog", "ELP_tstorm", "ELP_hail"), 
 row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

When subsetting, you can use `grep` on column names with `^` to indicate the start of the string:

```
head(iris[,grep('^Petal', names(iris))])
#   Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          1.4         0.2
# 2          1.4         0.2
# 3          1.3         0.2
# 4          1.5         0.2
# 5          1.4         0.2
# 6          1.7         0.4
```

Alternately, `dplyr` has a nice `starts_with` helper function within `select` which is for the same purpose:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% select(starts_with('Sepal')) %>% head()
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5
# 2          4.9         3.0
# 3          4.7         3.2
# 4          4.6         3.1
# 5          5.0         3.6
# 6          5.4         3.9
```